# select option *selected* attributes not working in chrome

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-select, forms

I have a code fragment similar to this:

```html
<select class="abcd" id="aaaa" />
<option selected>yes</option>
<option>no</option>
</select>
```

Firefox shows **Yes** as a default option when page loads.
But, same is not true with Chrome, and Safari. The select box shows up with a blank box and I have to click on the box to reveal the options and see what's the default one (Yes was chosen when the box is dropped down).

Can you please me understand if I'm missing some boolean argument here? Thanks!

Comment: [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/mqsmaa19/)

Comment: It works for me on chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/jvm0vzsm/

Comment: Yes, it works for me on a jsfiddle. But, for some reason, it doesn't in an enterprise application. Thanks for trying out.

Comment: Well then that would probably mean that there's more code somewhere that's affecting the outcome which you didn't post in your example. Please post a complete code example in your question that allows us to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

? It actually seems to work as expected in chrome and IE (sorry don't have Safari handy).
Did you try looking with dev tools at the cascading and computed style rules?  There might be a script or !important rule etc overriding your code.

Comment: I'm going to try debugging in a bit. Stuck with something else. Thanks for the input.